# Symfony2 - abstract entity only for inheritance, without DB table?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In Symfony 2.8 I have some entities which have the same fields, but for the purpose of data organisation I need them to be separate entities. Is it possible to create one abstract base class with all the fields, getters and setters and then just create new entities extending base abstract class, repeating as few as possible?

Example:
Let's say I have `Movie` entity, which has some people connected. People have different roles (actor, director), but let's assume they have only FirstName and LastName. I don't want to keep them in one table (with roles) for data separation purposes.
So I'd like to create one abstract `Person` entity, which will have `FirstName`, `LastName`, getters and setters. And then I'd like to create empty (as empty as possible) classes `Actor` and `Director`, extending `Person` and let Doctrine take care of the rest, so in DB I should have `actor` table with all the `Person` fields.

Is it possible to achieve something close to what I want?

Comment: Instead of creating new entity for each role, why can't you just create one role entity and association with people entity ?

Comment: I think you are looking for this: [link to oficial documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html)

Answer (score 0):

It just seems like basic inheritance. Since you do not want to persist the Person entity but those which inherit from it you can define your base Entity defining Doctrine statements at everything you want to persist but the Entity itself.

Then on the child Entity you define the rest of the fields you may want to persist, configure them to work with Doctrine and on the Child Entity annotations you define the table that is going to persist that particular entity + telling the Entity to inherit its parent Doctrine configuration.

Then you will have both the parent and the child Doctrine configuration and only the table configuration on the child so every child will be persisted on its own table.